# Writing to NTFS external HD attached to Windows 7 from OSX

Tags: windows-7, macos, ntfs

I have a Windows 7 computer on which I have an external 3TB HD attached. It is formatted NTFS, which is the way it came. Had I realized the hassles I'm going through, I might have reformatted it before I started using it, but it's too late for that now. So here's the thing. I want to do one of these things:

- Share a folder from Windows 7 and be able to write to that folder from OSX (my version is 10.8.5).
- Set up the drive and/or OSX so that I can write to the drive when I plug the drive into my Macbook Pro.
- Share a folder on my Macbook Pro so that I can access it from Windows 7.

Essentially, I have a bunch of folders on the Macbook Pro that I want to copy onto that external HD.

What I've tried ( following suggestions from https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4152122?start=15&tstart=0 ):

I have shared a folder in Windows 7. I can access it from OSX, but only in read-only mode.
I followed instructions for editing /etc/fstab and setting a LABEL= line there. I've done a similar thing with UUID.

I did not reboot after making those changes, but I unmounted and remounted the drive.

The username on the Windows 7 machine does not match the username on the OSX machine.

I suspect if I am able to attach the share using the Windows username (it's shared on a Windows workgroup), I might get it to work, but I don't see a way to do that.

EDIT:
The computer shows up in finder in the SHARED category, but if I click on it, it says Connection Failed. If I click the Connect As button, I get a message stating there was a problem connecting to the server.

On the Windows 7 box, I tried a couple of things on the off-chance they would make a difference. I turned network discovery on, and I change encryption level from 128 bit down to 40 bit. I'm not sure what else to try.

P.S. It turns out shares are not available from a Windows XP computer either. So apparently, there is something not set up right on my Windows 7 computer. I'm running the sharing diagnostics utility now (didn't realize there was one). It includes a network diagnostics utility that seems to be taking forever.

Comment: Which version of OS X, and which instructions did you follow? On my Mountain Lion laptop, I just tried a command of the form `mount -t smbfs smb://username:password@host.domain/share /path/to/mount/point`, and that worked (with a username different from my OS X account) -- it shouldn't be hard to set up the same mount in /etc/fstab, but the syntax might differ depending on your OS X version, so if you'll edit your question to include that and also a link to the instructions you're using, it shouldn't take much more than that to get you going.

Comment: In your example, what would host.domain be? Would that be the computer name of the computer I'm trying to connect to?

Comment: BTW, I get an error when I try the mount command as you have given it. Are you sure the "smbfs" is supposed to be there?

Comment: host.domain is indeed meant to represent the hostname of the computer you're connecting to -- but note well that you won't likely be able to use a Windows "computer name" in that position, as I don't think OS X does the WINS name resolution in which Windows "computer names" are meaningful. Use an IP address or a DNS name instead. Regarding the `-t smbfs` argument, yes, it's supposed to be there. What error do you get when you use it? It's possible that you don't have the `mount_smbfs` command, which is what `mount -t smbfs` maps to.

Comment: Also, again, what OS X version are you using, and what instructions are you following? It's a lot harder to provide useful advice without being able to look up version-specific details, and without knowing precisely how you're trying to do what you're doing.

Comment: My version of OS X is in the question, 10.8.5. Regarding the error I get, I don't get an error message, per se, but I get a listing of the correct command syntax. Trying the command without that did not produce that result.

Comment: Check [this cnet article](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-57588773-263/how-to-manually-enable-ntfs-read-and-write-in-os-x/) for native ntfs writing. I don't have a mac to confirm at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

I'll tell you the gui way:

In *Finder*, map a network drive. For the address, be sure to specify the *smb* protocol, as in

```
smb://127.0.0.1/c$/music
```

or whatever IP and share name you have shared out. You'll probably be prompted for credentials (I HOPE you didn't share it out to *everyone*), at which point you'll enter your Windows credentials.

As a side note When mapping network shares, the filesystem of the physical drive typically doesn't matter (yes, there are exceptions, but you should be fine in this instance).

Comment: That doesn't work. I get an error: "There was a problem connecting to the server "whatever". Check the server name of IP address, and then try again. If you continue to have problems, contact your system administrator. I get this when "whatever" is the computer name or the IP number of the other computer.

Comment: On the Mac, the connection dialogue includes a browse button. If I use that, the server appears in the list, but no shares are listed for it. Shares are listed for my Windows XP computer.

Comment: It turns out rebooting the Windows 7 machine resolved the share issue. So I'll withdraw that part of the question. I'd still like to know how to access the external drive directly, if possible.

Comment: You'll need an app that writes to ntfs for the mac. I know mac will write to exFAT natively (the latest version @ the time of this writing, it will also format to exFAT), but I don't know about NTFS. I want to say it won't, but I really can't remember.